# Reading Azure Table in Logic App to send mail

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a requirement to read entries from azure table on daily basis. Based on date field on that table, I need to query to select some entries and send it as a mail to a person. And additionally there is a mail ID field, once entries are filtered based on that date field, individually also I need to send mail.

I was not suppose to use any third party tool like send grid or mail jet. So not able to go for azure function or hosting console application as web jobs. When I check logic apps, there is some options to send mail using outlook.

If possible, can anyone please tell me how to achieve my requirement using logic apps. If any other options available suggest me too.

Comment: Hi, may I know if you can send email with entries success ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, if do not have any problem, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually my post was regarding both Querying Azure Table and Send the results to mail. Still I didn't get any help

Comment: Ok, I will try to help you query azure table tomorrow because I will off work soon.

Comment: May I know what does `Azure Table` refer to ? Azure table storage ? Or a table in azure sql ? And for the send email requirement, which email tool do you want to use ? Outlook ? or gmail ? or anyother ?

Comment: Azure Table Storage only. Mails will be sent internally. So preferably outlook

Comment: Ok, I will do some research and then update my answer later.

Comment: May I know if your requirement is to send email to the mail address in `mail ID` field ? If query many entries, do you need to loop all of the entries and send to each email address ?

Comment: Or just need to send one email to a specified mail address with all of the entries in it ?

Comment: @Hury Shen, Thanks for your reply. Both requirements are there. One cosolidated list has to send to one person. Next individual mails (Mail ID will be one of the column in that table) based on each entry.

Comment: Hi Kattesang, I have updated my solution. Please refer to my logic app.

Comment: If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: @Hury Shen, As of now I will mark you reply as Answer. Because it, really helped me to start my work. I have some more queries. But I will explore myself or post it as new thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your email account has O365 license, you can use "[Send an email (V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-an-email-(v2))" action in "[Office 365 Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook)" connector to send email.

[image]

[image]

If your email account doesn't have O365 license, it is a normal outlook email account. You can use "[Send an email (V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/outlook/#send-an-email-(v2))" action in "[Outlook.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-outlook)" connector to send email.

[image]

[image]

==============================**Update**==============================

Please refer to my logic app below:

**1.** I create a table in table storage, shown as below screenshot.
[image]

**2.** Use "[Get entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuretables/#get-entities)" action to get the entries of the table. Input `testDate gt datetime'2020-01-01T04:53:11.4584078Z'` into "**Filter Query**" box to filter the entries by field `testDate`.
[image]
**Please note**: Do not input `TESTDATE` in filter query because it seems case sensitive according to my test.

**3.** Add "[Create HTML table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#create-html-table-action)" action to convert the filter result of "**Get entities**" from json to HTML.
[image]

**4.** Then add "[Send an email(V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/outlook/#send-an-email-(v2))" action to send the email to one person which you want with entries in html.
[image]

**5.** After that, use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the json result from "**Get entities**" action.
[image]

You can click "**Use sample payload to generate schema**" button and input the json result into the box to generate the schema automatically.

**6.** Then add "**For each**" loop to loop `Body` from "**Parse JSON**" action, and send email to each mail address with the entries.
[image]

**7.** After running the logic app, I received the email. The email shows like:
[image]